# How to use proguard-maven-plugin to filter all maven dependencies when obfuscating code？

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I wrote the required maven dependencies in maven's pom.xml, and now I add proguard-maven-plugin to obfuscate the code, and hope not to obfuscate the dependencies written in pom.xml

The project depends on a lot of maven jars. Is there a configuration method to directly filter all maven jars?

How do I modify pom.xml or proguard.cfg?

---

A part of my pom.xml

dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-redis-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-pool2-version}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

plugin:

```
                <plugin>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                            <version>6.0.2</version>
                            <scope>runtime</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.14</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>proguard</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <attach>true</attach>
                        <attachArtifactClassifier>pg</attachArtifactClassifier>
                        <injar>original-${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                        <outjar>original-${project.build.finalName}-pg.jar</outjar>
                        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                        <proguardInclude>../proguard.cfg</proguardInclude>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

How do I filter these two dependencies when obfuscating the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally added the following parameters to the configuration file to solve the problem

```
-keep interface !com.kdgz.monitor.** {*;}
-keep class !com.kdgz.monitor.** {*;}
```

I don't know if this is the standard solution, but it did solve my problem.
There are some other small problems. I ca n’t understand the principle of the method I searched, but it can solve the problem.